# How to discourage answers in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, unanswered-questions

I can't tell you how many times I have seen a question get answered with a comment, then languish in the "unanswered" category.  I think these questions are not very in depth, and don't require a long answer.  But never the less, an answer should be an answer, not a comment.  I also think the answerer is probably new to the site and may be shy / hesitant to put their thoughts in an "official" answer.

Does anyone have ideas how to get people to use the site more properly?  Or is this not a big deal?

I have decided that I am going to start prompting the users with another comment, as in [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/arm-to-disassemble-and-assemble-notebook-at-home) post.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a big deal. I'm relatively new to the Stack Exchange community (though I've lurked StackOverflow for years), but this board in particular seems to be filled with people just like me, asking either the same questions I have or questions about issues I've had in the past.

That said, our answered question rate [is "okay"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics), partly because people answer in the comments of the question and partly because the correct answer is never accepted. There are relatively few questions that are open that do not have an answer, and I feel that of those, most are questions that should have been closed anyways [because](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/help-me-in-quadcopter-controlling) [they](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/what-happened-to-butlers-car) [are](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/arm-to-disassemble-and-assemble-notebook-at-home) [too](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7372/how-do-i-caefully-remove-the-top-green-cover) [vague](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/dynamics-of-parallel-manipulator), [some](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/heavy-omnidirectional-platform-suspension) [are](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/chassis-materials-for-hobby-weight-5-44kg-battle-robot) [very](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7068/how-the-strategy-changes-in-a-robcup-competition-without-connection-to-outside) [open-ended](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4702/advice-on-mounting-a-servo-for-a-nerf-sentry-gun) [design](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/actuation-of-three-reciprocating-blades-via-conversion-of-rotary-to-linear) [questions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/1-cm-accuracy-radio-rangefinder), and [others](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/diy-laser-cutter-for-small-acrylic-robot-baseplate) [are](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/looking-for-a-way-to-scan-cylindrical-objects) [essentially](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7085/models-algorithms-of-swarm-robotics-beheviors) [shopping](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/good-robotics-bio-engineering-prosthetics-graduate-programme-in-us-europe) [requests](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/tools-needed-for-static-and-dynamic-balancing) [or](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6606/cheap-wheeled-robot-without-tether-does-not-need-to-be-programable) [shopping](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7309/proprietary-movement-platforms) [recommendations.](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6773/all-inclusive-quad-copter-kit)

I don't have site admin capabilities, but I feel like administration in general here is just okay. As mentioned, if the OP abandons a question, it seems like nobody comes around afterward to assign the correct answer as "accepted", and questions that should be closed remain open.

I don't know what "powers" come with admin privileges, but I feel like the correct way to handle answers in the comments section would be to move the answer from the comments section to an answer and then assign that answer as "accepted". Again, I don't know if it's possible for admins to create an answer on behalf of another user, but if it's not it should be, for this exact reason. That, or add the ability to accept an answer from *any post* related to the question, not just the "official" answers.

Comment: I completely agree